# counter_cache is not working on a simple model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

My posts have_many upvotes. I want to add a counter_cache so I can quickly get the number of upvotes per post.

Post and PostUpvote models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_upvotes
end

class PostUpvote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

Migration to add the counter_cache column:

```
class AddPostUpvotesCountToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :post_upvotes_count, :integer
  end
end
```

In my DB, the post_upvotes_count column is empty, and from my logs I am still doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "post_upvotes"  WHERE "post_upvotes"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 1234]]` so this means the cache_counter is not working.  Any idea what I'm missing to get cache_counter working?

Comment: Is your post_upvotes_count column actually NULL or did you default it to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll back the migration

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then change the migration to

```
add_column :posts, :post_upvotes_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

Then migrate again

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you don't set the initial default, it won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I did this but the column is all 0's even after I upvote something - and Rails still seems to be doing a COUNT(*) out of the DB.

Comment: just got it! It was because I needed to do 'reset counters' in the migration :)